# How to call stored proc in bigquery with input as a result set?

Tags: loops, stored-procedures, google-bigquery, resultset

I want to call stored proc that take input of 3 parameters and those argument value should be col1, col2,col3 value of each row from select query and looped over result set.

```
  DECLARE A STRING;
  DECLARE B DateTime;
  DECLARE C DateTime;
  SET (A,B,C) = EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'SELECT b.billingaddress.state ,a.startdate, a.enddate, FROM `dataset.tablename1` a inner join `dataset.tablename2` b ON a.lendercompany = b._id group by a.lendercompany , b.billingaddress.state , a.startdate ,a.enddate';
 
 CALL dataset.GetMonthRentalDays (A,B,C)
```

Comment: can you provide more details please. maybe with pseudo-code so it is more clear what you try to achieve

Comment: Did you get some kind of error? What happens when you try to execute your code?